# Is the word "finicky" appropriate to describe fine, important, details, that may escape the inattentive eye?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context

In the sentence:

> In case you learned the language, you may be interested in these ***finicky*** details, as they often go unnoticed by the untrained or inattentive eye.

Consider we're talking about *fine-grained* detail about a language, which may escape a less experienced person's grasp (like the connotation of finicky does to me, as a non-native speaker).

Now, consider as well that the detail - despite seemingly trivial - might be or become interesting to look into, although it is often ignored. *E.g,* dialectal word usage specific to your town, that a foreigner will pick a 100% in its normal sense.

Also take into account that my question comes from the apparently disparate connotations I found in the dictionaries.
See:

**Oxford Learner's Dictionary**

1. **​(disapproving)** *too worried about what you eat, wear, etc.;
   disliking many things*
2. *needing great care and attention to detail*

**Merriam-Webster**

1. *extremely or excessively particular, exacting, or meticulous in taste or standards*

> My teacher is finicky about spelling.

2. *requiring much care, precision, or attentive effort*

> a finicky recipe

> **[disapproval]** Even the most finicky eater will find something
> appetizing here.

So it appears to me that there are a neutral and a disapproving connotation.

I also found the similar *fussy*, *fastidious*, *exacting* and to a lesser extent *dainty*, among others. All had definitions that seemed to imply an *actor* rather than an object, mostly with a disapproving connotation.

In my phrase, I am concerned whether 'finicky' doesn't feel *neutral*. I'm also interested in **alternatives that fit this context.**

Thanks.

Comment: I’d probably choose ***subtle*** instead.

Comment: @Jim Yeah, subtle fits. I'm looking for possible alternatives, though.
There's no precise reason for that, just curiosity.

Comment: You can say 'finicky' about yourself to be self-effacing, as it's not neutral. Finicky detail that is not negative is *fine detail*. If there's a detail that is important, you are not being finicky to note that detail.

Comment: @KannE thanks for noticing that, I hadn't seen it.

Comment: @YosefBaskin I appreciate your comment. That's the sort of insight I often feel that I need when I see new words that aren't commonly used in speech.

Comment: Certainly the term is used to refer to situations where attention to detail is required.  It's sort of metaphorical, though, and definitely informal.

Answer (score 1):

For the average reader, *Tiny* details

For the advanced reader, the way you have it sort of works. *finicky*
However, I prefer your own suggestion better; *Fine-Grained Details*

Comment: Can you include in your answer whether the word finicky is neutral? Terms like "sort of" and "I prefer" indicate opinion. Opinions posted as answers get pushback on this site.